# Evaluating the following limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} \frac{(1-x\ln{x})\cdot e^x-1}{x}$

Tags: limits

I am a student. Please help me evaluate this limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{(1-x\ln{x})\cdot e^x-1}{x}$$

**Edit:** I cannot use L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: do you mean $$\lim_{x \to 0*}\frac{(1-x\ln(x))e^x-1}{x}$$?

Comment: @projectilemotion yes

Comment: can you use L'Hospital?

Comment: without L'Hospital

Comment: *Mathematica* returns $\infty$.

Comment: I know but how to count it step by step

Comment: Maple says the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\frac{(1-x{\rm ln}\space x)e^{x}-1}{x}=\frac{e^{x}-1}{x}-e^{x}{\rm ln}\space x.$$

As $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$, $\frac{e^{x}-1}{x}\rightarrow 1$ and $e^{x}\rightarrow 1$. So as, ${\rm ln}\space x\rightarrow-\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$, we have,

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{(1-x\ln{x}) e^x-1}{x}=\infty.$$

Comment: Thank you man can you answer this question and solve limit without l'hopital rule http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2217571/how-to-count-this-limit-in-math